# How to set width of page in react js

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a simple react project where I have some dummy text. I want to set the width of the total page to 80%. This is the code I am using:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='main-container'>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**App.css:**

```
.main-container {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Even after doing this I am not getting the width to 80%. This is the output which I am getting:

[image: react_error]

Why isn't the width getting shrinked to 80%?

Kindly comment if more information is needed.

Comment: From screenshot it seems that page has taken with 80%. What are you trying to do can you explain a bit?

Comment: I think your css are applying just fine. Can you provide a sketch of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The width does seem to be 80%. Apply `margin:auto` to center the `<div>`. https://dev.to/mohamed_gt57/how-to-center-elements-in-css-46nc/#center-block-ele

Comment: I have to agree. The text is showing that the content is only taking up 80%. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to center the text so that there was equal space on both sides of the paragraph.

Comment: @NiceBooks, If I don't apply `margin:auto` and just use `width: 80%;`, then why is the paragraph getting left aligned to 0?

Comment: Getting left aligned is the default style.

Comment: But why isn't it obeying the `width:80%` attribute? Shouldn't it use 80% of the page and then get left aligned? What I mean is that it should some space to the left and then get left aligned.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
.main-container {
    width: 80%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: If I don't apply `margin:auto` and just use `width: 80%;`, then why is the paragraph getting left aligned to 0?

Comment: because when you add width 80% it will take 80% of parent div which is page itself and 20% empty space i.e. margin.
if you open the page in developer mode (inspect element) you will get an idea where 20 is actually margin.
on adding margin auto, it will divid the margin equally 10% 10% both the side and your component get center.

Answer (score 0):

It will help you use max-width if you want same space both side of paragraph.

```
.main-container {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```